# Send Ajax data to Laravel controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar, I need need to create a new event when user clicks on a specific date, I am using Laravel controller to store the data send by ajax request. I can create an event on calendar, but I cant send the data to controller and moreover browser tab freezes after creating the event. Anyone can correct where I am wrong? or provide better solution to the problem.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
var title = event_name;// Event Title:
var eventData;
if (title) {
    eventData = { //creates a new event on the calendar 
        title: title,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        allDay: allDay
    };
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true

    $.ajax({                        
        data:eventData,
        type: 'POST',
        url:"/projects/calendar/store", // your url
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'));
        },
        success: function(response) {
             console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

This is my Route file, I have tried both get and post but none is working.

```
Route::get('/projects/calendar/store','FrontEndController@calendarStore');
```

This is the Controller, it will only process data sent by ajax request but no view.

```
public function calendarStore(Request $request)   

{
$calendar = new Calendar;
Input::all();

$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$event_title =$request->input('title');
$start =$request->input('start');
$end =$request->input('end');

$calendar_event = Calendar::create([
    'user_id' => $userId, // I can get the user ID 
    'project_id' => 2,
    'event_title' => $event_title,
    'start_date' =>$start,
    'end_date' => $end
]);
}
```

Comment: Firstly you need to change your route to a post route. Within your ajax object you've set the type to POST as you're posting data, you have to do the same with your route.


Secondly have you tried checking your network tab and dd($request) within your calendarStore method? If not try this and see if you get to your controller method.


Thirdly add an error key to your ajax object which accepts a closure beneath `success: function() { ... }` in the same fashion and `error: function(response) { console.log('here', response); }` to see if you are getting errors when posting.

Comment: What are the errors? There has to be a AJAX error or apache log error being logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following modifications: and its working as Expected, once user click/selects on the specific day/day's it will ask for title and and save the event in database.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    var title = prompt('Are u sure you want to apply for job? Yes/No:');// Event Title:
    var start_time = moment(start).format();
    var end_time = moment(end).format(); //onclick get date 
    var eventData;
    if (title) {
        eventData = {
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            allDay: allDay
        };
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',//POST changed to GET
            url: "/projects/calendar/store", // your url                                                
            data: { //event data from global variable 
                title: event_name,
                start: start_time,
                end: end_time,
                event_id:event_id
            },
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'));
            },
            success: function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

Updated Route

```
Route::get('/projects/calendar/store','FrontEndController@calendarStore');
```

Updated Controller

```
public function calendarStore(Request $request)
{
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $event_title =$request->get('title');
    $start =$request->input('start');
    $end =$request->input('end');
    $project_id= $request->input('event_id');    


    $calendar_event = Calendar::create([
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'project_id' => $project_id,
        'event_title' => $event_title,
        'start_date' =>$start,
        'end_date' => $end
    ]);     
    return $calendar->all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your declaration of your ajax `data` parameter like this:

```
//creates a new event on the calendar 
eventData = {
    "title": title,
    "start": start,
    "end": end,
    "allDay": allDay
};
```

Comment: Quote properties are required for only that identifiers which are invalid. I don't think this is the issue, there must be something else.